# Removing a relation between entities in EF Code First Many to many relationship

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have an application built with entity framework 5 code first, where I'm using code first against an existing database. I have two entities, Foo and Bar, which are connected through a many to many relationship using a table in sql server with foreign key to each of the two tables. In code, the two entity types each have a collection of the other, and in the dbcontext they are mapped together like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
           .HasMany(e => e.Bars)
           .WithMany(s => s.Foos)
       .Map(l =>
         {
            l.ToTable("FooBar");
            l.MapLeftKey("FooId");
            l.MapRightKey("BarId");
         }
       );
```

The problem is that I can add relationship between the entities by adding eachother to their collections and saving, however when I do the opposite, removing eachother from their collections, the record in the relationship table are not being removed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just importing the bridge table in the model. If anyone knows how this is supposed to work, please leave an answer here.